# Verifying that EFI device path is valid

Tags: uefi

I want to check efi image path is valid, This is the code:

```
 gBS->LocateHandleBuffer (
         ByProtocol,
         &gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid,
         NULL,
         &NumberSimpleFileSystemHandles,
         &SimpleFileSystemHandles
         );
  for (Index = 0; Index < NumberSimpleFileSystemHandles; Index++) {
   TempImagePath = FileDevicePath (SimpleFileSystemHandles[Index], L"\\EFI\\BOOT\\boo.efi");
   if(IsDevicePathValid(TempImagePath,sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL)) == TRUE){
          //OK
  }
```

This code always returns that the path is invalid, I think there is a problem in the second parameter of `IsDevicePathValid`.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use this to determine if the file exists? I don’t think IsDevicePathValid will check that.

Comment: There also seems to be a typo: "boo.efi" should probably be "boot.efi".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsDevicePathValid returns false if the total length of the device path exceeds the value of the second parameter, MaxPath. Obviously it exceeds sizeof (EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL), which is 4. You should pass 0 for this parameter.

Comment: You were right, I was trying to check if file exists, The function `IsDevicePathValid` will not help.